# How to correctly create react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created a website using react js. In localhost server it is working, but when I upload my site to hosting, I faced one problem.

I have three routes, but when I try to go "website.com/admin" it returns me 404 error.

I tried to remove Switch but not working.

[image: My Code IMAGE]

The error message is : 
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: The server also needs to server the correct page when accessing any of the links. Not just the root link

Comment: On which website are you hosting ? And other path works but only admin not ?

Comment: @Freestyle09 not only admin, it was just example. only "/" works

Comment: @apokryfos it is woking in my local server.

Comment: @Freestyle09, 000webhostapp.com

Comment: Probably not an issue but I notice you have paths `/admin` and `/Dash`. Should you be using `/Admin`?

Comment: @camden_kid No, both not working

Comment: Try moving the word 'exact' in front of the 'path' keyword instead of in front of the 'component' keyword. What happens then?

Comment: @ErkebulanElzhan so your website is not working on domain right ?? Full webstie you have getting 0 response right ? On '/' and '/admin' and '/Dash' ?